# Router navigate to same current url

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-routing

I'm building a basic app using `@angular/core": "^5.1.3, "@angular/router": "^5.1.3"` and ng-cli. I've created a navbar with two navigation links(/home, /list) using `routerLink="..."` and `routerActiveLink="active"`. In the home component's view I'm generating a random ID.

All works good, but when I'm on the home page and click on the Home button again, the ID does not changed. I need either to refresh the page or to switch click between /list and /home.

I'd like the home component's view to be rendered again and regenerate that random ID(opposed to full refresh of the page) even if I'm currently in the home page.

Before posting this, I've found [1](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/13831) and [2](https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/19463), but still I didn't succeed. Can someone help with an example?

Comment: Example: https://coursetro.com/posts/code/111/Using-the-Angular-5-Router-%28Tutorial

Comment: Hi, I've managed to do what I want by keeping and generating the ID from a service that also exposes a re-generate function for ```(click)="..."``` action.

Though, I've been wondering if there is something to be done such as the whole component's view to be reloaded when the same nav bar tab is pressed(equivalent to switching between nav bar tabs). Thus, I need not to bind any ```(click)``` actions.